# Yii Active Record function BETWEEN

Tags: php, yii

Whats the right way to use BETWEEN in Yii Framework?

Code:

```
...
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'datetime BETWEEN '.$datetimemin.' AND '.$datetimemax;
$user = Users::model()->find($criteria); 
...
```

Error:

```
SQL: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '07:10:10 AND 2011-10-10 13:10:10)' at line 1.
```

Comment: Just a tip: use `$criteria->addCondition()` instead of `$criteria->condition`. Otherwise you are losing any previously set conditions or ones set by the CDbCriteria's constructor (if any).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

most correct

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('attributeName', 'value1', 'value2');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the "correct" way to do it in Yii.

But the error is because the dates need to be quoted.

```
$criteria->condition = 'datetime BETWEEN "'.$datetimemin.'" AND "'.$datetimemax.'"';
```